# Как создать 2е окно в приложении iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Как создать в конструкторе 2й и тд экраны в Main.storyboard. Например я создал авторизацию и нажимая далее перехожу на следующий экран. (Xcode 12.1). Спасибо заранее за ответ)

Comment: не очень понятен ваш вопрос, уточните пожалуйста

Comment: Создал первый экран на котором будет происходить авторизация, после нажатия кнопки далее открывается новый Tracker

Comment: просто добавьте новый viewcontroller свяжите через нажатие на кнопку при помощи segue, или вас именно эти вопросы и интересуют?

Comment: окей попробую, спасибо